# PHP: make selection with pQuery

Tags: php, curl

I have a html element looking like this.

```
<input type="hidden" id="my-id" name="id123" value>
```

I am using curl and pQuery library which can be found here: https://github.com/tburry/pquery.  pQuery should enable selections in a similar fashion as jQuery.

I would like to get the value of "value" with pQuery.

I tried this

```
$dom = pQuery::parseStr($html); // curl_exec returns $html
$value = $dom->query('[id="my-id"]')->val();
```

and this

```
$value = $dom->query("\#my-id")->val();
```

but is is not working. What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: Try `$dom->query("#my-id")->val();`

Comment: yep, that's it. Be sure to post as an answer